# Javascript statement with comma in php

Tags: javascript, php, operators

I found the following statement in a script and i need to copy the same functionality in php

```
(x = 2 * x, f > x ? x : f)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried to convert it to PHP?

Comment: don't know how to convert the comma...

Comment: In JavaScript a compound expression consisting of expressions separated by commas simply evaluates the expressions left to right and returns the result of the last expression

Comment: so in php this would be $x=2*$x; if ($f > $x) ... ?